# Python: Understanding and avoiding circular imports when using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I know, there have been a lot of questions on this already, but I still don't understand this specific situation I have:

I have a main package, which holds my main class, that has holds lots of useful things:

`main.py`

```py
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lots_of_important_attributes: SomeObject
```

Now I have some other packages, where I have classes, that help extending functionality, while accessing those important attributes:

`sub_module.py`

```py
import main

class Foo():
    def __init__(main_pointer: Main):
        self.main_pointer: Main = main_pointer

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.main_pointer.lots_of_important_attributes)
```

`sub_module2.py`

```py
import main

class Bar():
    def __init__(main_pointer: Main):
        self.main_pointer: Main = main_pointer

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.main_pointer.lots_of_important_attributes)
```

But now it gets tricky: I also need to be able to access the `sub_module.Foo` class in `main`, since there, all the stuff happens, so I have to import the `sub_module`:

```py
import sub_module
import sub_module2

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lots_of_important_attributes

    def do_something_else(self):
        foo = sub_module.Foo(self)
        foo.do_something()
        bar = sub_module2.Bar(self)
        bar.do_something()
```

This is obviously bad, since it creates an inifinte loop of circular imports.

I could of course only import the important attributes of class `Main` to `Foo`:

```py
import SomeObject

class Foo():
    def __init__(super_important_attribute: SomeObject):
        self.super_important_attribute: SomeObject = super_important_attribute

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.super_important_attribute)
```

But this also seems unsatisfying, since it's a lot of more work to type than just to create the pointer to `Main`.

I'm ruling out the options of just putting everything into one big file as well, for obvious reasons.

What it is the canonical way of avoiding this?
Also, why does this error only occur as soon as you have 2 sub_modules importing main and not with just one?

For reference, the `Main` class is a `PyQT5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow` and this (for me) unusual class structure came to be while trying to compartmentalize the windows in Qt a bit better.

Comment: Neither of your submodules seem to use anything other than the *name* `Main` for type hints. Use a forward reference (`def __init__(main_pointer: 'Main'):`) or use `from __future__ import annotations`, and you won't have to import `main` at all.

Comment: Technically, you're not wrong, though then I also loose the auto-complete features of editors, like PyCharm. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Heppi can't you just add `main_pointer` as argument of the `__init__`? Also, if Qt is what required you to do that, it might be useful to have a [mre] of what you're trying to achieve *practically*, not with just a "pseudo-code".